# Why is my query working on pgAdming but when I execute it from the server I get a query error (Error: Connection Terminated)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm working on my Capstone project and it requires to store some telemetry data on a database. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5 for the database and node for the server.

My problem is that when I try to send a query from the server I'm getting a query error [Error: Connection Terminated]. If I use `JSON.stringify(err)` I only see empty brackets as the result `{}`. What is interesting is that if I use pgAdmin client and execute the same query, the record is added successfully without any kind on error.

Here is the code I'm using in the server to send the query:

```js
client.connect(function(err) {
    if(err){
        return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
    }

    //Checks if there is survey data to process
    if(surveyFlag){

        //Query to insert survey record
        //Returns survey record's auto-generated id to use it when creating or updating the             //telemetry record in the database 
        var query = 'INSERT INTO survey_response (perceived_risk, actual_risk) '+
                    'VALUES (' + telemetryRecord.survey.perceivedRisk +', ' +                   
                                 telemetryRecord.survey.actualRisk +') ' +
                    'RETURNING survey_id';

        client.query(query, function(err, result) {

        console.log("Query: " + query);

                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return console.error('error running survey query', err);
                }

                surveyID = result.rows[0].survey_id;    

                //Testing
                console.log ("Survey response added with ID: " + surveyID);


        });

            //Close the connection  
        client.end();
});
```

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5? :) That's in early Beta still. Anyhow, have you look at [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), if you want to relieve yourself of more pain in the future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `client.end()` is put at the same level of the code `client.query()`.  Since `client.query()` is asynchronous, the `client.end()` gets called immediately after you start the query.  By the time the query comes back the client has already ended which is causing the problem.

Try placing the `client.end()` code within the callback function of `client.query()`.

```
client.query(query, function(err, result) {
  console.log("Query: " + query);

  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return console.error('error running survey query', err);
  }

  surveyID = result.rows[0].survey_id;    

  //Testing
  console.log ("Survey response added with ID: " + surveyID);

  //Close the connection  
  client.end();

});
```